# Is it possible to make a default value in input field of html and not editable using java script

Tags: javascript, html

is it possible to make a default value in input field of html and that value is not editable, after that we can add some value in it..
Ex: fist two characters are 'AB' is a default and not editable and after that we can add any numbers in same input field AB6382826 like this, can we make using java script, can anyone help?

Comment: why not using an element (like `span`) that has the text `AB` and an input next to it ?!

Comment: Users may find this auto-prefixing input confusing. As @ths suggested, it would be better to enclose the input in a span or label element with the AB text outside the input. Then it is clear to users and works in a more standard way.

Answer (score 1):

You may listen for the user input on your `input` field and always prepend `AB` to whatever the user has typed. You'd also need to apply in way you don't get redundant text in that field so we should always remove `AB` before prepending it once again to prevent redundancy.

Here's a live demo:

```js
const inp = document.getElementById('my-input'),
  /** the text to prepend, store it in a variable and use it whenever needed */
  textToPrepend = 'AB',
  /** the regular expression that will help us prepend the text by deleting the prepended text each time the user types in the field */
  prependRegEx = /^(AB?)?/;

/** listen for user input on the field and prepend the text as needed */
inp.addEventListener('input', () => inp.value = textToPrepend + (inp.value == textToPrepend ? '' : inp.value.replace(prependRegEx, '')))
```

```html
<input type="text" value="AB" id="my-input">
```

> Even though the above demo works as expected, the validation in the backend is highly recommended as i can use `JS` to send a value that doesn't respect your format.

Comment: This solution also works when pasting values into the input. +1

Comment: @Yogi Yes it does and also when you select all the text and delete it you'll get `AB` there. But as I have mentioned, I strongly recommend some server side validations as the above solution can be easily bypassed.

Comment: But the id can't be used in my existing code as it is already used

Comment: @Ash so change the id

Comment: @Ash as mentioned, you can change the `ID` as needed (which is obvious btw). Anyway, if you find my answer helpful, kindly, mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **Maskedinput.js**, or something like that in Jquery library or **imaskjs** for vanilla javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the input value on each input and use String.padStart method, like so:

```js
const inputVal = 'something';

const newVal = inputVal.padStart(inputVal.length + 2, 'AB');

console.log(newVal);
```

*Expected output: ABsomething*

Answer (score 0):

Putting `AB` inside a `label` and using `position:absolute` to place it inside the `input` & using `padding-left` on input for making the space for the label text.
inside the js i am doing the samething that `@catfish` did by getting the value entered by the user and doing `padStart()` on it to my initial characters i.e`AB`.
i am displaying the result inside the h1.

```js
function show(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let inputVal = document.querySelector("#newInputId").value;
  let newVal = inputVal.padStart(inputVal.length + 2, 'AB');
  document.querySelector("#newInputId").value = "";
  document.querySelector(".preview").textContent = `Your Value Is: ${newVal}`;
  console.log(newVal)
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: monospace;
  margin=0;
  padding=0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

#label {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: gray;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 4px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#newInputId {
  color: gray;
  padding-left: 25px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="show(event)" class="wrapper">
  <label id="label" for="newInputId">AB</label>
  <input type="text" id="newInputId" placeholder="Enter to Submit">
</form>
<h1 class="preview"></h1>
```

Comment: Is the AB value will be taken as input value and id can't be used again as it's already used in my existing code

Comment: i dont understand your question?

Comment: My question is that when you make that AB as a default value and user can add more values in front of that, here AB 272882 like this AB will be taken as a input value to the backend?

Comment: yes. if you `console.log(newVal)` you will see the result

Comment: check now. i added the console.log

Comment: you will see the value after hitting enter

Comment: Okay and in input tag I can't use the id again as it's already used in my existing code, is there any other solution for this?

Comment: just do different id.it doesnt matter

Comment: what id do you want to add to it?

Comment: Like  in my project there is a existing code for that  it will take  account numbers in input  field but the new requirement is that first two value should be default AB and it should be not editable and users can add only numbers to it, but input tag the id is already used of other purpose..

Comment: i changed the Id's

Comment: you can also change it to anything.....but make sure you do it in all places like i just did

Comment: I mean under input tag the 'id' field is already used, like id="newInputId"  The id is already used for other purpose in our existing code, can we add 'id' twise?

Comment: yes you can use it twice in js